# How to convert the month into uppercase in Crystal Report?

Tags: date, syntax, crystal-reports, formula, uppercase

In Crystal Report, I use the "Print Date" in the "Special Field" for my report. I have set the date to appear in the following form: Mar.01,2017 for example.

However, I couldn't use a correct syntax or formula to change **Mar** into **MAR**, which means an "uppercase" month name. I've tried to convert the month into string first, but it seems not work.

What is the correct syntax or formula to achieve the form I want?

Comment: can you post your formula here?

Comment: I use uppercase(cstr(crShortMonth)), but it shows error.

Comment: can you post error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula.

```
UCase( CStr( {V_WO_CRW1.START_TIME}, "MMM. dd, yyyy" ) )
```

You'll want to replace `{V_WO_CRW1.START_TIME}` with the field in your report that contains the date you want to print.  The format string can be modified as needed as well.  MMMM will print the month as OCTOBER instead of OCT for example.

I tested this formula in CR 2016 Pro and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula.

```
UCase( CStr( DataDate, "MMMM, yyyy" ) )
```

For me it worked very well.